# Windows Server 2008 R2 - Can't connect RDP over the Internet

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall

I have two networks: Domain and Public, Domain is a VPN connection and Public is the local connection to the network. This is not a domain controller or a DNS/DHCP server.

I can connect via RDP from the local network (192.168.1.*), from the VPN network (10.1.2.*), and from the VPN network over the internet.

I cannot connect from the internet (anywhere besides where the server is VPN'd)

Wireshark indicates that the server is getting packets, and the audit log is indicating that the packets are being dropped.

Advanced Firewall has explicit options to allow RDP, and has no deny policies. I have also tried turning Firewall off completely to no avail.

I'm really lost on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it has to do with the VPN connection, to fix use this suggestion from [.NET Answers](http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2008/08/26/bypass-vpn-for-regular-traffic/):

> In Vista:
>
> Go into the Control Panel and click
>   the “Network and Sharing Center” icon.
>
> On the left panel of the resulting
>   screen you should see a link, “Manage
>   network connections.”  Click it.
>
> The next screen will have icons for
>   all of your connections.  There should
>   be one for your VPN.  Right-click it
>   and select “Properties” from the menu.
>
> In the “Properties” screen, click the
>   “Networking” tab and then select
>   “Internet Protocol Version 4″ and
>   click the “Properties” button.
>
> Click the “Advanced” button.  This
>   will bring up a new window where you
>   can un-check “Use default gateway on
>   remote network.”
>
> OK out to save everything.

Apparently the issue is that VPN connections do all traffic over VPN, including incoming. Not sure why it explicitly was ignoring incoming traffic that Wireshark showed, but this works.